# What Necessitates a Different Protocol for Email?

Tags: http, email, smtp

In what way is HTTP inappropriate for E-mail? How (for example) does the statefulness of IMAP benefit client development?

What actually are the arguments for keeping them separate other then historical and backwards compatibility reasons?

Comment: HTTPs is nothing more than HTTP wrapped by a cryptographic layer. It has nothing to do with SMTP which is a different protocol made for a different purpose. Would you use FTP for HTTP? I don't think I see the point of your question.

Comment: Jack, I'm asking is why would we use a different protocol if we could achieve the same result with HTTP. From my understanding, you could create an email like functionality if you used HTTP Post.

Comment: From your point of view you could implement any non p2p protocol just by using HTTP because it is able to send and receive data. In the same way you could implement an array that requires random access with a linked list but it wouldn't work so nicely, that's the same story. Sending mails is a specialized business and it is managed by a specialized protocol, I don't see anything strange in it.

Comment: Jack, I've rephrased my question and perhaps it will make what I'm asking more clear. From my perspective, the argument for keeping them separate is because they're different not because one is better than the other for the job.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SMTP, IMAP, and HTTP are specialized application-level protocols.  If there was a generic application-level protocol which all of these could inherit from, you could usefully refactor things, but since that is not the case, wedging the other protocols into one of the existing protocols is hardly worth the effort, and would hardly simplify things.

As things are now, the history and backwards compatibility is not just a cultural heritage, it is also a long and complex process of defining application-specific features for each protocol.  SMTP is store-and-forward, which introduces the need for audit headers (`Received:` et al.).  IMAP was designed for concurrent access to a data store, which is what made it necessary to introduce state (who are you, where are you authorized to connect, which folder are you connected to, what have you already seen, read, or deleted).  HTTP is fundamentally a pull protocol (pull down a web page) and the `POST` facility carries with it a lot of functionality specific to the CGI protocol and the overall content model of HTTP.

Answer (score 0):

SMTP is a protocol that identifies the sender and the recipients to send individual mail messages, each mail server accepts (or not) mail to forward, eventually reaching the destination. HTTP is meant for anybody to connect to the server and look at (mostly the same) contents. They are quite fundamentally different, and so it makes a lot of sense to use different protocols.

Comment: Vonbrand, do you mind elaborating on why we couldn't use HTTP Post to send the message instead of SMTP? Or how they're fundamentally different?

Comment: Sure, you could use POST to send data, but that data would essentially be what SMTP sends: Destination(s), origin, message itself. SMTP is just tailored to exactly that kind of interactions, while HTTP is tailored to a different use.